# Tizen Modify label text

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm working on a native widget for a wearable-3.0 in Tizen Studio that will display three stats.  I've been trying to find code to change an existing label existing in the widget but have failed.  Any help getting me pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Loren

Comment: It depends on some parameters like based on which conditions you want to change a label and what changes you want to apply on that. Would you please share more detail about what you're trying to implement? Also please share your source code here.

Comment: I stumbled across the data model and the ability to request json data from a server.  Now I just need to figure out how to perform calculations on the data that is returned

Comment: Ok. Generally, to change the text of a label in Tizen native you may try to set text of that label based on your required conditions. Please use below line of code inside the update function of your app.

elm_object_text_set(label_to_change, "<align=center>Updated Text</align>");
 
It will set the updated text on the label. Hope it'll help.